# realm java force creating of new realm instance

Tags: realm, realm-java

If you create new RealmConfiguration and then call `Realm.getInstance(configuration)`

it will use the internal cache. If i delete the realm file, then create new instance of configuration calling of Realm.getInstance(configuration) won't create new Realm instance and realm file (or reload it) again. I need to force Realm to do so and skip or clean the internal cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `realm.close();` seems to does the job. But you have to make sure you capture only one local Realm variable or one close() call won't work.

Bad example:

```
public void importRealmFile(Context context) {
    Realm realm = contexts.getImportContext().getRealm();
    Storages importStorages = new Storages(contexts.getImportContext().getRealm());
    realm.close(); // doesn't free the realm from the cache
```

Good example:

```
public void importRealmFile(Context context) {
    Realm realm = contexts.getImportContext().getRealm();
    Storages importStorages = new Storages(realm); 
    realm.close(); // works good
```

Comment: Every instance returned by `getnInstance()` needs to be closed by calling `close()`. Realm maintains a reference counter internally.